# Tensorflow - Convert timestamp to day of the week

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-transform

I have a model that operates on features, one of which is an array of timestamp of previous events.

I would like to compute for each element of this array, the day of the week for each timestamp ("Monday" to "Sunday" or a integer in [0, 7))

I would like to do that in the graph because I want my model to be able to replicate this transformation when I'm making prediction on device.

Day of the week is just one of the information I would like to extract from the timestamp, ideally I would also get year, month, etc...
The closest I found so far is the [tfa.parse_time](https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/text/parse_time) which does nearly the exact *opposite* of what I'd like to achieve.

Is there an existing implementation of such an operator? If not, how could I go about implementing this taking into account leap years, time zones, daylight saving times, etc...?

Comment: Have you found a solution to your problem?

Comment: I image it shouldn't be too complicated to do this by hand, as long as you account for the algorithm to compute leap years. I'm looking for the actual algorithm to do this myself. I'll post what I find.